# How to sign a section of xml using ecdsa with sha 256?

Tags: cryptography, x509

I am using python for most of my programming. I am trying to sign the `<ds:SignedInfo>` portion of my XML document. However, I am having a lot of trouble doing so in python. I generated my public and private keys with the following commands in open SSL: (I believe this is an elliptic curve based key pair, please verify)

```
openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-256 -out ECPARAM.pem
openssl req -newkey ec:ECPARAM.pem -keyout privateKeyEC.key -out mycsrEC.csr
```

I then got the `mycsrEC.csr` signed by a CA. I saved the certificate in a `issued_cert.cer` (but I think it was formatted as a PEM file; it has BEGIN CERTIFICATE, END CERITFICATE). Also, my private key has a password associated with it, and the file is stored as `BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY`. I believe with this setup, I should be using the `ecdsa-with-sha256` signing algorithm, but I am having trouble implementing this.


To be clear, my requirement is to sign the `<ds:SignedInfo>` element in my XML document, using the `issued_cert.cer` certificate and the `privateKeyEC.key` private key, and this should be with the `ecdsa-with-sha256` digest.


1.) I would prefer a python solution, but I am okay with a java or c++ solution, in that order of preference.


2.) Do I have the required resources to perform this operation?


3.) How can I convert my certificate to a readable text file? It has some encoding which makes it unreadable?


4.) Any questions for additional context are encouraged

Comment: You probably refer to XML-DSig compliant signing, which includes canonicalization, so it probably makes sense to use a library that supports the corresponding functionalities, see e.g. [here](https://www.decalage.info/en/python/xmldsig).

Comment: If I use https://pypi.org/project/lxml/ and convert an element tree to a string using `lxml.etree.tostring(xml)` , does this output return a canonicalized XML?